# .htaccess redirects not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

We've setup a new website for www.immo-turkuaz.be on the domain www.turkuaz.be

In order to get through all the SEO value to the new domain, we've uploaded this .htaccess on www.immo-turkuaz.be

```html
Redirect 301 / http://www.turkuaz.be
Redirect 301 /nl/tekoop.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod
Redirect 301 /nl/in-een-notendop.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/over-turkuaz/wie-zijn-we
Redirect 301 /nl/vastgoedinfo.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/infosessies
Redirect 301 /nl/vragen.html  http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/faq
Redirect 301 /nl/index.html http://www.turkuaz.be/
Redirect 301 /nl/getuigenissen.html http://www.turkuaz.be/getuigenissen
Redirect 301 /nl/over-turkije.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/over-turkije
Redirect 301 /nl/regio.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod
Redirect 301 /nl/contact.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/contact
Redirect 301 /nl/projectbegeleiding.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/projectbegeleiding
Redirect 301 /nl/links.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/links
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/91/k2-deluxe-residence.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/17-k2-deluxe-residence
Redirect 301 /nl/bezichtiging.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl
Redirect 301 /nl/activiteiten.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/info/over-turkuaz/hoe-werken-we
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/86/zen.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/24-naam-van-de-residentie
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/9/q-spa-resort.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/23-q-spa-resort
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/34/city-highlights-ii.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/22-city-highlights
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/14/the-hill.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/21-the-hill-side
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/78/felicia-residence.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/20-felicia-residence
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/35/orka-valley-spa---sport-complex.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/19-orka-valley
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/22/the-valley.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/18-the-valley
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/38/golden-heights-ii.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/1-new-golden-heights
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/57/klaros-residence.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/18/q-garden.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/16-q-garden
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/56/sarigerme-heights.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/17/majestica.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/15-majestica
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/59/lakeshore-golf.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/bodrum/item/14-lakeshore-golf
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/10/babylon.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/13-babylon
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/15/agora.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/12-agora-f11
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/16/citrus-garden.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/11-citrus-garden
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/84/spring-3-appartement-a3.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/9-spring-3-a3
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/82/royal-hills.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/8-royal-hills
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/21/mandarin-garden.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/7-mandarin-garden
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/23/tropicana.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/6-tropicana
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/33/orka-park.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/5-orka-park
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/25/sunset-residence.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/27/olive-grove.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/4-olive-grove
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/29/okeanus.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/3-okeanus
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/32/custom-build-villa.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/side/item/2-custom-build-villa
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/42/uzumlu-mountain-villa.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/41-oasis-uzumlu-villa
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/40/crown-villa.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/41/orka-gardens.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/40-orka-gardens
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/43/oasis-uzumlu-villa.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/41-oasis-uzumlu-villa
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/52/centre-point-studio-s-en-appartementen.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/42-centre-point
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/85/duplex-city-highlight-i.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/43-duplex-city-highlight
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/53/olivia-apartments.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/54/olive-gold-villas.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/44-olive-gold-villas
Redirect 301 /nl/detail/55/orka-diamond-collection.html http://www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod/dalaman-fethiye/item/54-diamond-collection
```

Now, this doesn't work as it should....

e.g.

www.immo-turkuaz.be/nl/tekoop.html redirects to www.turkuaz.be/nl/tekoop.html

While it should redirect to www.turkuaz.be/nl/aanbod (as you can see in the .htaccess content.

Only the homepage redirects well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You might put the Homepage-Redirect to the most bottom of the list. Otherwise it will always redirect  "/" and all containing files/folders first.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to your very first rule:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.turkuaz.be
```

Which is catching all the URLs and redirecting same to new host.

Move that line to the bottom of your .htaccess and retest after clearing your browser cache.